# Magento 2: Get all product types pro-grammatically in system admin?

Tags: magento2.3, product-type, product-types.xml

Magento 2 provides product types as simple, bundle, configurable, grouped, gift card, etc.

Is there any way programmatically to fetch all the product types which exist in the Magento codebase including custom product type also?

This should probably scan the `product-type.xml` which is located in the respective module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer below code can be useful in any class.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTypeListInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface;
```

Below code for construct method.

```
public function __construct(
     ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTypeInterfaceFactory $productTypeFactory
) {
     $this->productTypeConfig = $productTypeConfig;
     $this->productTypeFactory = $productTypeFactory;
}
```

Core function to get all product types

```
public function getProductTypes()
{
    if ($this->productTypes === null) {
        $productTypes = [];
        foreach ($this->productTypeConfig->getAll() as $productTypeData) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTypeInterface $productType */
            $productType = $this->productTypeFactory->create();
            $productType->setName($productTypeData['name'])
                ->setLabel($productTypeData['label']);
            $productTypes[] = $productType;
        }
        $this->productTypes = $productTypes;
    }
    return $this->productTypes;
}
```

Refer: `/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductTypeList.php`

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner way: inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type` and call `toOptionArray()`